# Edits Rejected because they conflict with a subsequent edit shouldn't count as a rejected edit on profile

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I edited a question for formatting today and received two Approved reviews before it was rejected for conflicting with a subsequent edit because a user with enough rep to automatically make edits made essentially the same change as me.

While this doesn't bother me too much, I feel that an edit that was rejected for conflicting with a subsequent edit shouldn't count as an edit rejection on your profile, since it would have been approved as someone else (the OP or a user with higher rep) not made a similar change.

For reference, my edit was: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8187490

Comment: The edits on that are a mess already, and haven't been done very well - there's a line or two of code at the bottom that hasn't yet been fixed. I would suggest that the person who subsequently edited it used the "reject and edit" button in the review queue, if they did then it should show as a rejection in your edits.

Comment: But my edit fixed the lines on the bottom, it was the subsequent edit that overwrote mine but didn't format completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree and think that what we have here is several edits that have been inexpertly done.

Judging by what the review screen shows me I would have modified your edit too as it seemed you added a lot of `>` to blockquote the errors - this is the right thing to do but you should only have needed a few of them at the most (my edit only required one).

Having said that, the subsequent edit was absolutely incorrect - he used code formatting for the exception details rather than a blockquote. He also missed the few lines of code at the bottom.

I would suggest that the person who edited it subsequent to you (chiwangc) used the "reject and edit" button in the review queue - if they did then it should show as a rejection in your edits. But the fact that they rejected it doesn't mean they got it right or made a better edit than you.

In any case I rolled it back to the start, then re-edited it. It still isn't quite right grammatically, but it's not a big problem at this stage - the OP is still missing essential information.

I would chalk this up to an unfortunate sequence of events and not worry about it too much.

Comment: One thing to note, and I've gone back and forth on this.  I think that using blockquotes for logs sometimes makes them harder to read. Using code formatting sometimes provides the best view of logs since it keeps each log line on one line, same as if you were looking at them in an IDE.  Note also that using code formatting keeps the proper indentation, which can really help sometimes, especially for Android stack traces.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at hand. While that particular edit may be troublesome, it was only in the question for reference. The actual feature request is still valid, imho.

Answer (score 3):

I agree regarding the feature request. If "inexpertly done" handling leads to poor statistics, then such cases should not be counted at all or need to be approved again. However endless edit review steps are definitely no solution.

The "subsequent edits" are already treated specially in regards to an edit ban. It makes sense to also treat them specially when listing approvals/rejects themselves. Otherwise they may only influence reviewers decision to approve/reject besides giving any benefit.

It probably still suffices to get a good statistics for approvals/rejections without subsequent edits.