# Why are my reviews affected by reviews which were rejected by community due to conflict with a subsequent edit?

Tags: support, feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295164) is similar, but it is not a duplicate, as it has no suitable reasons or answers.

When I was trying to edit a post, I saw an attention warning saying: **Some of my previous edits were rejected and I should review my recently-rejected edits before continuing:**

[image: Warning]

After that I reviewed all my edits and among them I found that around eight of nine were rejected by Community due to a conflict with a subsequent edit:

[image: Rejection]

**My Questions are:**

1. I think this is not my fault. Why is it counted and shown as rejected reviews in my profile?
2. Will Stack Overflow ban me from reviewing in future when the number of such rejections increases?

Comment: If 8 of 9 were rejected by conflict, focus on the one that wasn't. You won't be automatically banned for your edits being rejected due to a conflict with a subsequent edit.

Comment: Although, if you do have a high percentage rejected because of conflicts with future edits, for your *own* feedback, you might want to wonder why so many of yours conflict with others.

Comment: @corsiKa The same happened to me today. I took about 30 minutes to edit the question and this edit was _approved_ already. But later the edit got rejected because of a subsequent edit. This is a little frustrating because I even created a screenshot of the described problem and added it to the question. So the consequence of this is: don't invest too much time to edit, because it's more likely to get rejected because another user is _faster_?

Comment: @ventiseis Your situation is an unfortunate side effect of a good but imperfect system. If that was happening *often* then I would say you need to look at changing the mechanics of how you do edits. Of course, once you have 2,000 rep, it doesn't matter anyway - you can edit at will and this all becomes moot (for you).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Edits that were rejected because of an edit conflict [don't count towards the ban nor towards the warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277928/792066):

> Until recently, the edit-ban system completely ignored rejections by
>   Community; since edit conflicts could trigger such rejections, using
>   those made it extremely likely that folks editing new posts would be
>   banned for no fault of their own.
>
> This presented a problem for implementing warnings, however: the
>   warning criteria has to be evaluated every time someone opens the
>   editor, and pulling in the data needed to exclude Community's
>   rejections made that unacceptably slow. This actually ended up
>   blocking implementation of the very-popular warning feature for a long
>   time, but eventually **we got around it by recording the reason for the
>   rejection with the edit itself and simply excluding edits rejected for
>   that reason.**
>
> That change was followed by a revamp for how the "Improve" feature
>   worked for rejections. Now instead of rejecting edits while applying
>   them to the post anyway, it completely discards the edit in favor of
>   one the reviewer submits themselves - a behavior much closer to that
>   of edit conflicts, but with the notable difference that this rejection
>   is intentional on the part of the editor. Given this distinction (and
>   the fact that we can now trivially differentiate between the two
>   scenarios), it made sense to have these rejections count towards
>   warnings and bans, while **still excluding the unintended "conflict"
>   rejections.**

So, if you have a warning, it wasn't because of an edit conflict, but because [another edit of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11148185) was explicitly rejected by reviewers.

Comment: Note: A single rejected edit is enough to bring up the warning.

Comment: I must be really tired right now - read this all, a single time, and understood **nothing**.

Comment: @mvai yeah, Shog can cause that impression.

Comment: He surely does!

Comment: @mvai But with Shog9's avatar it always seems so reassuring, whatever it says. Now, with Braiam's avatar instead, ..... ;)

Comment: So, I am not sure if that rejected edit was correct.  Admittedly, it could have been a better edit: remove the entire "Thank you" clause, as well as the "I could not solve this problem" (which is redundant).  And I guess the link description might be wrong.  However, [vard's later edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35205869/revisions) is an example of a *good* edit on the question.

Comment: That edit should've been approved - and I'm surprise Vard didn't make a similar change.  I agree that other changes would've been nice, but that edit ought to have been accepted by our current edit standards.

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure which edit you are talking about...

Comment: @Braiam The OP's edit that you linked to.