# Why is reputation points not gained by my question with upvotes on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I have recently asked [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316355/why-are-my-reviews-affected-by-reviews-which-were-rejected-by-community-due-to-c/316369) on Meta Stack Overflow and that question got some few upvotes. I am really wondering why even a little bit of my reputation is not affected with those votes? Is there any circumstances in Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Be happy votes on Meta *don't* affect your reputation. Downvotes happen a lot here, and can mean something as simple as "I disagree with you." Having an unpopular opinion is okay, though, and shouldn't cause you to lose reputation. By design.

Comment: @CodyGray hehe ok....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Meta [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page states the following:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is
>   the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly),
>   though you earn separate badges.

Comment: Thanks for informing. I was really unknown about this. I think this question will be getting heavy downvotes.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna You can always delete it if you don't think it's valuable anymore.

Comment: @skrrgwasme May I delete this question then ? But it is warning me not to delete.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna It's giving you that warning because you have accepted an answer on it. You can either remove the accept and delete it, or just leave it and wait for it to be closed as a duplicate. I just suggested the delete option because you're probably right that it will collect downvotes - you can get rid of it if you don't want a downvoted question hanging around in your question history.