# Edit rejected that shouldn't have been rejected: is there a way to make it disappear from my log?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I proposed [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23121614) and it was rejected. The reason: "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post" which is clearly false because I was just formatting the text. Actually, after my suggestion, the author [did the very same edition](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56328407/revisions) a couple of minutes later. I have the feeling my comment was clear enough "fixing end code" and the reviewers didn't look carefully the edit, because it was kind of hidden at the end of the post. I assume I could have written a more detailed comment such as: "fixing end code: attention! look at the end of the code!", but still...

All in all, my edit was finally applied by the author itself as I already mentioned, but in my edit log now I have 1 more rejected edit. Is there a way to "amend" that?

I found other similar questions such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295164/edits-rejected-because-they-conflict-with-a-subsequent-edit-shouldnt-count-as-a) or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290903/community-rejected-edits-displayed-as-rejected-is-misleading) (among the several questions about rejected edits) but none of them addresses exactly my concern.

Comment: No, you can’t make it disappear from your profile.

Comment: You're right that the edit shouldn't have been rejected.  But it's a single reject; it won't have any impact by itself on your ability to suggest more.

Comment: The rejection reason was wrong, tbh. The suggested edit took text from the code block and formatted it correctly (as non-code). Your edit message could have been a bit better though, to make it easier for reviewers.

Comment: "end code" is a somewhat meaningless phrase. Perhaps instead of "fixing end code" you could have written "formatted text mistakenly included in code block as text".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's currently no way to disassociate yourself from a contribution that was never technically accepted. We can do things around specific revisions, but not so much things that never actually become revisions.

The way the system surfaces some of the information around edits is far from optimal. In some cases we don't flout it for you *enough* (well, beyond badges) and in other places the language is a little harsh. Because an edit wasn't accepted doesn't necessarily mean it was a bad edit, sometimes things just go sideways in review.

We don't want people to feel like they have a black mark on their profile. Yet, at the same time, we need to surface patterns of people using the system completely incorrectly (often with not-so-great intentions) and reviewers who see the history are the ones that frequently spot the bad patterns and alert moderators. Automating detection there is ... sketchy, at best.

I'd love a feature request for how we could make the experience better (given the constraints that we can't simply take it away) - could be as simple as just how we show the history so someone without a lot of inside knowledge would know to look at the proposed revision directly for context? Anyone *with* inside knowledge about how the system works wouldn't think twice about seeing a sprinkling of suggestions that didn't get accepted, so it's the outside world checking out your profile that's the primary use case.

Or, would simply changing it to "not accepted" sufficiently solve for that, even though it means the same thing? I can see how REJECTED feels like a big red stamp, even when it's not all in caps.

Either way, we're open to changing it as it does come up kind of regularly since one's participation on the site has come under a little more scrutiny by the outside world in recent years. We don't want language in your profile that makes you feel bad, but we have to maintain the goal of keeping as much transparency into activity as possible.

Comment: While wording is important let's not pretend to this community and their outside lurkers that we only have a language problem. Just replacing doomed words feels ... wrong ...

Comment: @rene The idea of just having edits that weren't accepted age away pretty quickly (in conjunction with showing the activity with more clarity and context) seems like it might work. That satisfies the use case of being able to see abusive patterns easily enough, while also taking away the fatigue of something that just didn't go right (X) days or weeks ago from lingering.

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer. Perhaps you could "accept", "not accept" and "reject" an edit. If it is negative, it is rejected. If it is kind of neutral (good intention but not a good result), then it is "not accepted". The "not accepted" edits shouldn't necessarily be displayed in your profile or elsewhere. Not being publicly displayed doesn't mean they are not counted: if some user enjoys playing foolish making a lot of these harmless edits, you could still detect it. If a reviewer wants to do a very similar edit, (s)he could use "not accept and edit" instead of the current "reject and edit"

Comment: I'm personally a bit worried that ageing away "negative" stuff might give the impression these Q/A site is a happy place where anything goes. I mainly triggered on *let's replace a negative sounding word with something sweet*. I'll wait for the FR before I decide on my final position.

Comment: @xavier a review has two main options (covered by 4 buttons) as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGrVt.png) and then [this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEOCQ.png) to add the mandatory reject reason. Where would the difference between not accepted and rejected been taken into account?

Comment: There could be the buttons: Approve, Improve Edit, Not approve and edit, not approve, reject and edit, reject, skip. The following page could be the same. Also: you could have only Approve, Improve Edit, Not approve and edit, not approve and skip. In the second dialog, there could be a checkbox "this edit was made with bad intention". Also: the options "spam or vandalism", and "causes harm" could be considered as "rejected" and shown as "harmful"; and "no improvement", "irrelevant tags" and "attempt to reply" as "not approved" and then not shown negatively for future edit requests.

Comment: Oh god, no, @Xavier. The way to solve a problem with people making poor choices in a review queue is absolutely *not* to double or triple the number of choices. Furthermore, we’re not asking reviewers to make a decision about the *editor*; just the edit. There doesn’t need to be that many choices. Rejecting and “not approving” are 100% identical. It is terrible UX to have two options that mean and do exactly the same thing. I still do not see what problem you are trying to solve.